# VLookup inequality error

Tags: excel, vlookup, inequality, vba

I need to know whether a car in class A that has length B falls in its proper length range. I want to VLookup, via VBA, its class in a table that has maximum and minimum length values for each class. My code, where column 23=length, column 16=class, column 101=returns whether it's not in the right range.

```
Dim ClassCodeTable As Range
Set ClassCodeTable = Worksheets("Class Code Tables").Range("A:G")

Range("A1").Select
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To Lastrow
If Cells(i, 23).Value > Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 16), ClassCodeTable, 3, False) And Cells(i, 23).Value < Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 16), ClassCodeTable, 4, False) Then
    Cells(i, 101).Value = ""
    Else
    Cells(i, 101).Value = "Length Range Error"
End If
Next
```

This code returns a 1004 error, *unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class.* but this approach works when I VLookup whether car in Class A with characteristic C ***equals*** the expected categorical value for Class A in ClassCodeTable. It seems to me that the VLookup value returned is not being stored as number, even though all the values in the lookup table are numbers.

Is there a way to convert the VLookup value into a number that can be checked against an inequality?

Comment: remove the worksheetfunction and only use the application.vlookup

Comment: @NatG the error message displayed does not match your assessment of the error. VLookup returns a Variant variable, so the comparison is valid if the values are numbers. There might be a problem with invoking the Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup twice in the same statement. did you tyry to split the test into two steps?

Comment: strangely, i tried your code and it works perfectly but when i name the worksheet ClassCodeTable without spaces in the name. When in insert the spaces i get: runtime error 1004 - application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: Given that your narrative refers to the 'table that has **max** and **min** length values for each class' and that 'this approach works when I Vlookup ... **equals** the expected categorical value', could you humour me and double check that the **minimum** values are in column C and the **maximum** values are in column D?

Comment: Thank you everyone! My code is now working (though the two VLookup's on my Mac is slow, in the future I might try the approach below). @ScottCraner I think removing the worksheetfunction was key.

Comment: @ A.S.H. at first I thought the same and tried removing one of the VLookups and had an unbounded inequality, but it returned the same error. I think it was the WorksheetFunction issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate method to do the same thing, no loop required.  I tested it given your described setup and it ran successfully for me:

```
Sub tgr()

    With Range("CW2:CW" & Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row)
        .Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF('Class Code Tables'!A:A,P2)=0,""Class not found""," & _
                       "IF(AND(W2>=VLOOKUP(P2,'Class Code Tables'!A:G,3,FALSE)," & _
                              "W2<=VLOOKUP(P2,'Class Code Tables'!A:G,4,FALSE))," & _
                           """"",""Length Range Error""))"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Or if you'd prefer to have the formula all on one line:

```
        .Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF('Class Code Tables'!A:A,P2)=0,""Class not found"",IF(AND(W2>=VLOOKUP(P2,'Class Code Tables'!A:G,3,FALSE),W2<=VLOOKUP(P2,'Class Code Tables'!A:G,4,FALSE)),"""",""Length Range Error""))"
```